# Нанесения на картинку текст

Tags: img, watermark

Подскажите, как нанести текст или url на картинку? Проблема в том, что фото уже имеются в папках, на сайте сделал watermark, они наносятся, но есть сайт, на который идёт экспорт через xml он формируется под ссылку http://site.ru/img/1111/foto1.jpg

```
$img_ptrn = "/{*.[Gg][Ii][Ff],*.[Jj][Pp][Gg],*.[Pp][Nn][Gg],*.{Jj}[Pp][Ee][Gg]}";
$upload_path="";
chdir('../');
$images = glob($upload_path . "img/" . $row['id'] .  $img_ptrn, GLOB_BRACE);
chdir('export');
foreach ($images as $value) {
    $img = "http://site.ru/" . $value;
    $md5 = md5($value);

    $xml_content .= <<<img
    <image>{$img}</image> img;
```

Надо как-то при обращении к ссылке наносить текст или url, а ещё лучше logo.

Гугл и яндекс уже помог с watermark это на сайте подгружается js. А вот как это сделать не могу найти ни решение ни намёк, по обращению на прямую ссылку.

Comment: Зачем? Если будет милион запросов к картинке Вы будете милион раз наносить водянойзнак? Воспользуйтесь **Grunt**, настройте его смотреть в Вашу папку и к новым картинкам добавлять watermark.

Comment: Да можно и так но 1-проблема фото уже существуют в папках, 2-я не все сайты принимают фото что бы на них было что то написано.

Answer (score 0):

Собственно вопрос решен вот так может кому пригодится. в корень сайта кидаем файл 
watermark.php
С кодом:

```
header('content-type: image/jpeg'); 

// получаем имя изображения через GET
$image = $_GET['image']; 

// создаём водяной знак
$watermark = imagecreatefrompng('http://site.ru/images/1.png');   

// получаем значения высоты и ширины водяного знака
$watermark_width = imagesx($watermark);
$watermark_height = imagesy($watermark);  

// создаём jpg из оригинального изображения
$image_path = $image;
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_path);

//если что-то пойдёт не так
if ($image === false) {
    return false;
}
$size = getimagesize($image_path);

// помещаем водяной знак на изображение
$dest_x = $size[0] - $watermark_width - 5;
$dest_y = $size[1] - $watermark_height - 5;

imagealphablending($image, true);
imagealphablending($watermark, true);

// создаём новое изображение
imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $watermark_width, $watermark_height);
imagejpeg($image);

// освобождаем память
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Там где надо выводить картинки пишем путь вот так 
в моем случаи это так

http://site.ru/watermark.php?image=img/12385/image-15-02-16-01-00-11.JPG

Comment: Отформатируйте код, это просто не уважение.

Comment: Да я бы с удовольствием чет не получается сделать как с верху.

Comment: Спасибо огромное Makarenko_I_V